# Create new columns based on rows

Tags: r

If I had a matrix like:

```
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    2    8
[3,]    3    9
[4,]    4   10
[5,]    5   11
[6,]    6   12
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how I might create a new matrix from the above that looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    7  3    9    5    11
[2,]    2    8  4    10   6    12
```

Comment: What's the logic ? odd rows on row 1 and even rows on row 2 ?

Comment: @Tensibai they want to split the matrix into 4X4 chunks and then cbind them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We create a grouping variable with `?gl` and use the arguments `n=nrow(m1)`, `k=2` and `length=nrow(m1)`.  We `split` the matrix ('m1'), `unlist`, and create a new `matrix` with `nrow=2`.

```
 matrix(unlist(split(m1,as.numeric(gl(nrow(m1), 2, nrow(m1))))),nrow=2)
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #[1,]    1    7    3    9    5   11
 #[2,]    2    8    4   10    6   12
```

Or another option is converting to `array` by specifying the dimensions.  Here I used `c(2, 2, 3)` as we can get a 2x2 matrix for the first two dimensions and the third is based on the `nrow(m1)/2`.  Then, we can permute the dimensions of the `array` using `aperm`, concatenate (`c`) to form a `vector` and convert to `matrix`.

```
 matrix(c(aperm(array(t(m1), c(2, 2,3)),c(2,1,3))), nrow=2)
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #[1,]    1    7    3    9    5   11
 #[2,]    2    8    4   10    6   12
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(1:12, .Dim = c(6L, 2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here' another option: First the matrix is transformed into one with two rows, then the odd and even numbered columns are rearranged:

```
m3 <- m2 <- matrix(c(m),nrow = 2) #take data from original matrix, convert it into a matrix with two rows and store a copy in m2 and m3
m3[,seq(1,ncol(m2),2)] <- m2[,1:(ncol(m2)/2)] #define the odd-numbered columns of m3
m3[,seq(2,ncol(m2),2)] <- m2[,(ncol(m2)/2+1):ncol(m2)] # same for the even-numbered columns
> m3
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    7    3    9    5   11
#[2,]    2    8    4   10    6   12
```